# How to update a list object where matching condition using java 8

Tags: java, java-8

How to update a list object where matching condition using java 8

list --> Obj to iterate

```
    list.stream().filter(d -> { 
        if(d.getAvailableTodayInPerson() == true && d.getDistance() > dis) {
            d.setAvailableTodayInPerson(false);
            d.setAvailableTodayOutPerson(true);
        }
    });
```

Comment: you should not update the objects in the streaming pipeline. You can read more about this here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html

Answer (score 3):

It's simple actually. You can do something like this:

```
list.stream()
                .filter(d-> d.getAvailableTodayInPerson() == true && d.getDistance() > dis)
                .foreach(d -> {
                    d.setAvailableTodayInPerson(false);
                    d.setAvailableTodayOutPerson(true);
                });
```

Comment: This changes the original list instead of just applying an update if the condition is matching. I'd remove the collection and assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean?

```
list.stream().forEach(d -> {
     if(d.getAvailableTodayInPerson() == true && d.getDistance() > dis) {
            d.setAvailableTodayInPerson(false);
            d.setAvailableTodayOutPerson(true);
     }
 });
```